# Query error: there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am getting an error of

```
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

for my code

```
create table comm_Customer(CustomerID numeric primary key, 
                           CustomerName varchar(20),  
                           Address varchar(30),  
                           PhoneNumber numeric,  
                           foreign key(CustomerID)  
                               references comm_ShoppingCart(CustomerID));
```

Comment: Show DDL for `comm_ShoppingCart` table. *an error of* The field `CustomerID` in `comm_ShoppingCart` table is not indexed as unique one.

Comment: Is your foreign key the correct way around? Looking at this (without seeing comm_ShoppingCart) it means every customer can only ever have one shopping cart because CustomerID in comm_ShoppingCart must be unique. I think you want to place the FK on comm_ShoppingCart and reference CustomerID on comm_Customer so that a sinle shopping cart has one related customer but a customer can have multiple shopping carts.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear, you are trying to incorporate a `FOREIGN KEY` on table `comm_Customer` that says that the `CustomerID` (which is it's primary key) is also related to table's `comm_ShoppingCart` `CustomerID` column. This would mean that every customer might have a shopping cart (but only 1), since CustomerID has to be a primary key (or unique) on the `comm_ShoppingCart` to correctly identify a unique row of that table with the foreign key relationship.

I believe the relationship is the other way arround, `comm_ShoppingCart` `CustomerID` should reference table's `comm_Customer` `CustomerID` which *IS* a primary key and won't display this error message.

If this is the case, you can add the `FOREIGN KEY` with an `ALTER TABLE` if it's already created:

```
ALTER TABLE comm_ShoppingCart 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_comm_ShoppingCart_comm_Customer 
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) 
    REFERENCES comm_Customer (CustomerID)
```

If you really want the other way around, you have to create a `UNIQUE` constraint (or index) on `CustomerID` column on the `comm_ShoppingCart` table:

```
ALTER TABLE comm_ShoppingCart
    ADD CONSTRAINT UNI_comm_ShoppingCart_CustomerID
    UNIQUE (CustomerID)
```

... which will fail if you have more than 1 cart for a particular customer.